# Spring Boot Security With JWT Token Tricks and Best Practices

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, single-page-application

Looking for a good explanation for to following:
Once we identify a user (by any of the safe methods) we can generate a JWT token ang give it back to the user to identify themselves for a limited time without having to re-authenticate.

- How do we ensure that the correct user is using the correct token. Example, what if `user 2` stole the token of `user 1`, or what is `not a user` stole the token of `user 1`. Are we blindly going to trust the token? How to protect from this case?
- What if `user 1` grabs the token and modifies it to add some extra privileges? How to protect from this case?

Let's assume token is served in a cookie and it is not `httpOnly`, since UI needs to read (or decode) the content to grab some of the information from it's content.

Answer (score 1):

> Are we blindly going to trust the token?

Yes, it's the principle of a bearer token. If someone stole it, he can impersonate the regular user. Against this, there is two mechanisms:

1. The token has a lifetime that can be relatively short.
2. In some implementations, the token can be revoked.

> What if user 1 grabs the token and modifies it to add some extra privileges?

The token is signed with a cryptographic algorithm. If you modified it, it's signature would become invalid.

Comment: Point 2. Is reassuring. For Point 1, is there any common way to cross validate current user vs token user? I suppose tracking in session would partially defeat the purpose of using JWT tokens.